# Error in sqoop action in oozie while fetching data from teradata to hive

Tags: hive, oozie, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using HDP 2.3. I am getting the following error in sqoop action in oozie while fetching data from teradata to hive.

**Sqoop action in my `workflow.xml`:**

```
 <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.3">
        <job-tracker>${hadoop_jobTrackerURL}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${hadoop_nameNodeURL}</name-node>
            <job-xml>lib/hive-site.xml</job-xml>

  <configuration>
        <property>
              <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.user.classpath.first</name>
                    <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${hadoop_yarnQueueName}</value>
       </property>
  </configuration>

  <arg>import</arg>
  <arg>--connect</arg>
  <arg>jdbc:teradata://192.168.145.129/DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=DS_TBL_DB</arg>
  <arg>--username</arg>
  <arg>dbc</arg>
  <arg>--password</arg>
  <arg>dbc</arg>
  <arg>--driver</arg>
  <arg>com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver</arg>
  <arg>--query</arg>
  <arg>select * from ds_tbl_db.catalog_page WHERE $CONDITIONS</arg>
  <arg>--hive-import</arg>
  <arg>--hive-table</arg>
  <arg>catalog_page123</arg>
  <arg>--target-dir</arg>
  <arg>/user/root/db/catalog_page1234</arg>
  <arg>-m</arg>
  <arg>1</arg>
  <arg>--verbose</arg>
```

**NOTE:** I added `tdgssconfig.jar` & `terajdbc4.jar` and all hive dependency jars in `/share/lib`. Also tried with including the dependencies in the lib folder for workflow.

**Error Stack:**

> ERROR [main] tool.ImportTool (ImportTool.java:run(613)) - Encountered
>   IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "hive": error=13, Permission denied
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.util.Executor.exec(Executor.java:76)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:391)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:344)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:245)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:514)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:177)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
>           at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:186)
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
>           ... 31 more